# how to display the data getting from database in the table view in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have the two pages those are login and display page.when I click the submit button in login page then the second page is to be displayed with tableview of data getting from database.But I got the data from database and I need to display it in tableview .The problem is to display the data in the table view in xcode
I am taking the table view in .xib file 
NSMutableArray *userArray = [NSMutableArray array];

```
    int result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(itemdetails, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) ;
    if( result == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
        {

            NSString *usernamedb  = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
            NSLog(@"dbvalue=%@",usernamedb);

            NSLog(@"Count of rows:%d",count);
            [itemcatg addObject:usernamedb];
        }
    }
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
```

then it give the error in adding subview to the submit button in login page as in below line of code

```
[self presentModalViewController:subview animated:YES];
```

Comment: @rani - you might want to accept a few answers to questions.  You might get more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a an SQLite abstraction such as the following will help:
https://github.com/jameswomack/CCData

That set of classes allows you to easily get SQLite data into native objects such as NSArray so you can do this:

```
cell.text = [arrayFromDatabase objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```